# Emma instrumenting classes incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, code-coverage, emma

From working with EMMA I have noticed that it fails to instrument correctly causing the class to become mangled. Below is a simple example highlighting this issue.

```
public void showProblem() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

### Instrumented class

```
public void showProblem()
{
    boolean[][] tmp3_0 = $VRc; if (tmp3_0 == null) tmp3_0; boolean[] arrayOfBoolean = $VRi()[1]; int i = 0; arrayOfBoolean[0] = true; tmpTernaryOp = tmp3_0;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            Throwable e;
            System.out.println(e);

            e++; arrayOfBoolean[1] = true; arrayOfBoolean[2] = true; } while (e > 10); arrayOfBoolean[3] = true;
    }
    catch (Throwable localThrowable1)
    {
        System.err.println(localThrowable1); arrayOfBoolean[4] = true;
    }
    arrayOfBoolean[5] = true;
}
```

Notice that it is attempting to increment `e` of type `Throwable` and using this within the `while` loop.

I have found that by moving the try catch logic within the `for` loop it resolves this. As highlighted in the below code.

```
public void showProblem() {
    for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Instrumented class

```
public void showProblem()
{
    boolean[][] tmp3_0 = $VRc; if (tmp3_0 == null) tmp3_0; boolean[] arrayOfBoolean = $VRi()[1]; int i = 0;
    Throwable e;
    arrayOfBoolean[0] = true; tmpTernaryOp = tmp3_0;
    do {
        try { System.out.println(i); arrayOfBoolean[1] = true;
        } catch (Throwable localThrowable1) {
            System.err.println(localThrowable1); arrayOfBoolean[2] = true;
        }
    i++; arrayOfBoolean[3] = true; arrayOfBoolean[4] = true; } while (i > 10);

    arrayOfBoolean[5] = true;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced these issues?

### Setup

- Windows 7 64
- Java 1.6.0_24 64-bit
- Emma v2.0, build 5312

## Solution

So it turned out that the problem was to do with the debug information that eclipse was building into the classes. This was observed when using the Android generated ant scripts to execute `javac` and similarly caused the problem. Disabling this enabled EMMA to successfully process the class files.

I hope this information will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested under Windows XP with Java JRE 1.6.0_35 and EMMA 2.0.5312 without any problems. For me the decompiled code (using JAD) looks like this:

```java
public void showProblem()
{
    boolean aflag[] = ($VRc != null ? $VRc : $VRi())[2];
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        aflag[0] = true;
        do
        {
            aflag[2] = true;
            if (i > 10)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
                aflag[1] = true;
            } else
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        aflag[3] = true;
    }
    catch (Throwable throwable)
    {
        System.err.println(throwable);
        aflag[4] = true;
    }
    aflag[5] = true;
}
```

P.S.: I think in your code sample you actually wanted to use `i < 10` in the `for` loop, not `i > 10`, didn't you? ;-) Anyway, I used your code just as to make sure to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It still happens with that corrected. I'll update the question with more information regarding my setup.

Comment: So our EMMA version is identical. Can you maybe try with a more recent JRE 1.6, optionally even a 32-bit version, just to find out where exactly the problem is? Some difference in our respective setups must break your code.

Comment: So I upgraded to the latest JDK 1.7u25 compiled the class with that version and ran EMMA over it with the same version and it now looks correct. I'll repeat with 1.6 and see what the outcome of that is.

Comment: It's now working correctly when compiling running emma from the command line. Perhaps it was a mismatch of with javac within eclipse.